# Why is the output being overwritten for this javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

Expanded a previous question and it is working fine with the exception to the daily output. As the user enters each week/daily intake of supplement packs it should display to screen until the number of days entered is met. If a user input 2 weeks and 3 days (number of days packs were taken each week) the output should look like:

```
Week 1
Number of packs taken on Day 1 = 2
Number of packs taken on Day 2 = 1
Number of packs taken on Day 3 = 3

Week 2
Number of packs taken on Day 1 = 1 etc....
```

My code keeps writing over Week 1. I'm sure this is something simple that I overlooked. Maybe a variable to hold each weeks input? My code thus far...thanks for the help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Daily Supplement Intake Log</title>
<script>
function getSup() {
    var numWeeks = parseInt(document.getElementById("week").value);
    var daysPerWeek = parseInt(document.getElementById("day").value);
    var sum = 0; 
    var i = 0; 
    var total = 0; 

    while(i < numWeeks) {
       var d = 0; 
       var grandTotal = 0; 
       var maxPacks = 0; 
    var highDay = 0; 
    while(d < daysPerWeek){
        var packsTaken = prompt("Enter the number of packs taken on week " + (i + 1) + " and day "+ (d + 1), "");
        total = parseInt(packsTaken);
        document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML+="Number of packs  for day " + (d + 1) + " = " + total + "<br />";

            if(packsTaken > maxPacks){
                maxPacks = packsTaken;
                highDay = d;
                }
        sum += total;
        d++;
    }
    grandTotal += sum;
    i++;
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML="Week " + i + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML="Week " + i + " 
    subtotal is " + sum + " supplement packs." + "<br>" 
    + "Week " + i + " largest day is " + maxPacks + " packs, on day " + d + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("output4").innerHTML="The total for these weeks  
is " + grandTotal + " supplement packs." + "<br>";
}

</script>
<body>
<header><h1>Daily Supplement Packet Log</h1></header><br>
<section>
<div class="align">
<label>Number of weeks:</label>
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="week" value=""><br>
<label>Number of days per week:</label>
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="day" value=""><br></div>
<div id="button">
<button type="button" id="log" onclick="getSup()">Enter number of packs  
taken each day</button></div> 
</section>
<div id="output1"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
<div id="output3"></div>
<div id="output4"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using html comments in JavaScript?

Comment: Can you fix up your code so that it matches what you're actually using? There are a lot of stray line breaks and those HTML comments would cause lots of JavaScript parse errors.

Comment: Removed all the comments. Don't know why I do it...just do, apologies.

Comment: You don't have to remove all comments.  You just have to remove anything you added for this question.  Comments are fine, but the comments you used were HTML comments instead of JS comments and they caused the code to fail because they are syntax errors.  Next time, just copy the code exactly as you've written it.  With comments and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `document.createElement` method to dynamically create and order output divs. [JSFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/obtghg5a/)

First replace your `<div id="output1"></div>`, ...2, ...3, and ...4 divs with:

```
<div id="outputs"></div>
<div id="total"></div>
```

...and then swap your `getSup` function with this:

```
function getSup() {
    var numWeeks = parseInt(document.getElementById("week").value);
    var daysPerWeek = parseInt(document.getElementById("day").value);
    var sum = 0; 
    var i = 0; 
    var total = 0; 
    var d = 0; 
    var grandTotal = 0; 
    var maxPacks = 0; 
    var highDay = 0; 
    var packsTaken;
    var tempDiv, weekListText
    var outputs = document.getElementById("outputs");

    while(i < numWeeks) {
        d = 0; 
        grandTotal = 0; 
        maxPacks = 0; 
        highDay = 0; 
        weekListText = '';
        while(d < daysPerWeek){
            packsTaken = prompt("Enter the number of packs taken on week " + (i + 1) + " and day "+ (d + 1), "");
            total = parseInt(packsTaken);
            //document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML+="Number of packs  for day " + (d + 1) + " = " + total + "<br />";
            weekListText += "Number of packs  for day " + (d + 1) + " = " + total + "<br />";

            if(packsTaken > maxPacks){
                maxPacks = packsTaken;
                highDay = d;
            }
            sum += total;
            d++;
        }
        grandTotal += sum;
        i++;

        //document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML="Week " + i + "<br />";
        tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
        tempDiv.innerHTML = "Week " + i;
        outputs.appendChild(tempDiv);

        // formerly known as output2    
        tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
        tempDiv.innerHTML = weekListText;
        outputs.appendChild(tempDiv);

        //document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML="Week " + i + "subtotal is " + sum + " supplement packs." + "<br>" + "Week " + i + " largest day is " + maxPacks + " packs, on day " + d + "<br>";
        tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
        tempDiv.innerHTML = "Week " + i + "subtotal is " + sum + " supplement packs." + "<br>" + "Week " + i + " largest day is " + maxPacks + " packs, on day " + d + "<br>";
        outputs.appendChild(tempDiv);

    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML="The total for these weeks is " + grandTotal + " supplement packs." + "<br>";
}
```

This is mostly the same as the original, but I've rem'ed out the old `innerHTML` assignments and moved the `var`s up to the top of the function to reflect actual variable scope.

Comment: The fiddle works how I want it. Trying  to understand what is actually happening as the data is entered and output to display. Much appreciated...going to digest your code for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the html, you do not append to it like you do in the loop.

```
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML="Week " + i + "<br />";
document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML="Week " + i + "
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML += "Week " + i + "<br />";
document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML += "Week " + i + ";
```

but that is not going to make the output you want since they are the same sections. You really should be appending new elements to the page.

```
var header = document.createElement("h2");
header.innerHTML = "Week " + i;
document.getElementById("output1").appendChild(header);

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "new content";
document.getElementById("output1").appendChild(div);
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it. He wants each week to have a header row and detail rows. Your solution puts all of the header rows together in a single div, all the detail rows together in the next div, etc.

Comment: Exactly, I want a section for each weeks input. Eventually as I improve my skills hoping to maybe attach to a database.

Comment: The reason you're seeing that behavior is because you are literally overwriting what's already there.  Whenever you do `document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML="things";`, you are overwriting what was in that div before.  The answer is correct - the last half explains how you can append elements to the page, which is what you want to do rather than just overwrite what's there.  And for future reference you should copy your code EXACTLY as you are running it - for what reason did you add a bunch of comments that cause the code not to compile?  Leave only the comments you already have.

Comment: Haven't learned those methods yet but understand how and why they should work. Will play around with my code and see if that will clear up the way I want the input displayed back to the user. Thanks!